# Best practice for handling writing to external sd card?

Tags: android

My app allows users to browse their file system to select a location to save a file. Unfortunately, 4.4 users are no longer able to save to external sd cards. All workarounds I've found online are couched as being "not particularly good ideas", but other applications are currently succesfully saving to external sd cards, so I assume these workarounds are in use.

Is there a safe/smart workaround or a recommended best practice for dealing with this issue?

Some code that throws an exception on 4.4.2 device:

```
public class SdSample extends Activity 
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        File external = new File("/storage/extSdCard/DCIM/");
        File textFile = new File(external, "textfile.txt");

        try
        {
            textFile.createNewFile();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(textFile);
            fos.write("Hello".getBytes());
            fos.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            Log.e("", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is only the MediaFile hack which uses a Media Content Provider. But it does not work on all devices. E.g. here it failed on a Samsung Galaxy Note3 Neo. Here I found the MediaFile hack: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2634840

The official way to solve the problem is the Storage Access Framework:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

On Android 4.4, this works only for single files which the user has to select. At least you have then full access to this file, even in the data directories of other apps (on SD). But as far as I understood, it's not possible to e.g. let the user choose one directory and then have full access to this in the future.

This should come with the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, but it's API21. And I'm eger to have Lollipop on a device with a SD Slot, could not test yet ;-) Anyone here with a Moto G or LG G3? :)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your response. I tried running your MainActivity test app on a galaxy note3 and it fails making the initial test directory, giving notice "Failed to create base directory: /storage/extSdCard/MediaWrite". Additionally, I get FileNotFoundExceptions when trying to make use of your MediaFile class elsewhere (without using your test app). Do you think this is because of the device I'm using (I will try another)? Any suggestions of ways to make this workaround work in this case?

Comment: Also, I tried on a galaxy s4 with the same results.

Comment: I think the MediaFile class is not worth to spend any more time with. I just tried it on a Galaxy S5 which was rooted and where the SD problem was manually solved, and there, the MediaFile hack does not work. So either the Storage Access Framework, or let the user root the device.

Comment: Any clue how other applications o get around this? The application EZPDF, for example, seems to have found an effective workaround...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this help you much, but this is what I use when I have to write something onto SD card. This is a slightly modified version of code I found in [iosched project](https://github.com/google/iosched). It returns a folders under which you are allowed to create subfolders and files. It takes care for different Android versions too.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static File getBestAvailableFilesRoot(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        // In KitKat we can query multiple devices.
        // TODO: optimize for stability instead of picking first one
        File[] roots = context.getExternalFilesDirs(null);
        if (roots != null) {
            for (File root : roots) {
                if (root == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getStorageState(root))) {
                    return root;
                }
            }
        }

    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
        // Pre-KitKat, only one external storage device was addressable
        return context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
    }

    // Worst case, resort to internal storage
    return context.getFilesDir();
}
```

Android 5.0 [adds more support](http://lifehacker.com/android-lollipop-will-open-up-sd-card-access-a-lot-more-1655843428) over where user's files are stored. You might have a look in that new API as too.